# What to do to fill the void when a Torah giant dies

Tags: death, rabbis

I want to do something to fill the void left in the world from the passing of a Torah Giant.
All the Torah that he learnt, all the Mitzvos that he did, all the merit that this world had because of him - is now not here.

Does anyone have a source for an appropriate way to perpetuate the Torah, Mitzvos, and Gemilas Chasadim that a Torah sage left behind?

(Note: I'm asking my question due to the most recent Gadol BaTorah who just passed away, but my question is not referring specifically to him.)

Comment: Add on a Mishna or minute of Torah learning each day. Try to improve a small thing in an area that you need to. Help others

Comment: dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31499/759

Comment: pashute yid, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Not to presuppose actual, authoritative answers to the question, but I suspect that your desire to perpetuate the fallen *gadol*'s Torah, etc. is the beginning of its own fulfillment, especially actualized through the public bit of Torah learning. Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I'd say no, since this is specifically about filling the void and perpetuation, and that one is not so specific, as indicated by [your answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/31500/2) which fit that one but not this one.

Comment: take on to improve yourself in the areas where he excelled

Comment: Print his sefarim and chiddushim, so it should be שפתיו דובבות בקבר

Answer (score 3):

Ye'aros Devash by Rabbi Yonasan Eibeshitz writes that when a Gadol dies, his middos become accessable to everyone, and each person can pick one area to emulate and thereby acquire one aspect of the Gadol's greatness.
I also saw that Rabbi Avigdor Miller answered this very question by saying: Fill the void by yourself becoming a Gadol! 
These are two ideas I saw, and I am sure there are others, too.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the answers! Hope to see you around. :)

Comment: where is the Ye'aros Devash