# When a tzaddik dies, does he leave his positive traits in this world?

Tags: sources-mekorot, death, middos-character-traits, tzaddikim

I heard it said once that, when a righteous person (*tzaddik*) passes away, they somehow leave their positive character traits in this world to be used by others.

Does anyone know the source for this concept? Does such a source exist?

Comment: Hi user9727. Why do you think there is such a source? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Consider taking this short [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site. For general help see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/53312/759

Comment: @DoubleAA why dont you post that as an answer?

Comment: @DoubleAA If you wont post it, if you dont mind, I will.

Comment: @meva An unsourced internet post is worth very little as an answer here IMO.

Comment: Can you clarify what it means to "leave their positive character traits in this world to be used by others"? I'm thinking of a few different interpretations to such a statement.

Comment: For example, Rav Eliyahu Mansour SheLIT"A in a derashah on Parashat Haye'i Sarah brings the commentary asking why the parashah is called "Haye'i" (Life of) Sarah when she passes away right at the beginning of the parashah. The answer he brings is that the lessons taught to us, and the impact made on us and the world, by the tzadiqim is never lost such that they are never considered to have truly "died" (i.e. their teachings are never forgotten).

Answer (score 1):

I hear this a lot in hespedim (eulogies) of gedolim. Rabbi Nissan Kaplan said this regarding Rav Elyashiv and also Rav Nosson Tzvi Finkel.

The source I have often heard quoted for this idea is in [Melachim II 2:9](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09b02.htm#9):

> When they had crossed, Elijah said to Elisha, "Tell me, what can I do
>   for you before I am taken from you?" "Let me inherit a double portion
>   of your spirit," Elisha replied.