# What is the black pin called that mourners wear?

Tags: clothing, funeral-burial-levaya, symbols-symbology

What is the name of the black pin that one wears at a funeral, and are there any customs around them to know about? It's a black circle, pinned, and there's a black ribbon affixed to it.

Comment: "[The use of ribbons attached to clothing in order to avoid rending the actual garment is incorrect](http://www.crcweb.org/ask_rav/mourning.php)."

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8229

Comment: @Fred, thanks. I added the MY link to Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a Jewish practice to [tear one's clothes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8229/how-to-tear-kriyah) when in mourning. In recent times, it has become common for non-Orthodox Jews to tear a black ribbon pinned to their clothes rather than the clothes themselves in order to avoid damaging an article of clothing.

I am not sure whether using the ribbon satisfactorily fulfills the obligation according to the letter of Jewish law, but at least [Chabad.org](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/281558/jewish/Keriah-The-Rending-of-Garments.htm) seems to imply very strongly that it does not.

> How shallow, how disappointing, how pitiably trivial, therefore, to symbolize these authentic sentiments not by an act of historic and religious significance, but by the little black ribbon or button--invented by enterprising American undertakers!

As far as a name goes, I don't think there is any special name for this. I think it is generally just called a black ribbon. I have heard some people refer to it as a "*keriah* ribbon" after the custom of *keriah* (tearing).

Comment: That's so cheap! They can't even tear their clothing in mourning for a dead relative?